# Writing list<String> in csv java using CsvPrinter

Tags: java, list, csv, delimiter, apache-commons

I have `List<String>` which I'm writing to a csv file but each row is written on one cell. How can I split them through "," ? I tried to set the delimiter but still it isn't working.
**Code**

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter("D://new.csv", true);
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
            csvPrinter.printRecords(myList);
```

Comment: Can you share a sample data of your `myList` ?

Comment: And share how you built the myList ? there might be better solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [`documentation`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html#printRecords-java.lang.Iterable-) states, when you give a `List<String>` it'll use it a one record, ie one row, ie each `String` in a cell.

> If the given collection only contains simple objects, this method will print a single record like printRecord(Iterable)

---

You need a code that use the fact that each `String` is in fact a row, like

- passing each `String` splitted a separate record

  ```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String row : myList)
      csvPrinter.printRecord(row.split(","));
  ```
- Split all `String` then pass the whole list as a list of records

  ```
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
  List<String[]> myListSplitted = myList.stream().map(row -> row.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
  csvPrinter.printRecords(myListSplitted);
  ```

Comment: There had better not be any commas in each String.

Comment: @WJS He talked about commas, that's why i used them

Comment: True, but sometimes, OP's don't realize that split isn't that smart.

Comment: That worked but I'm getting a warning. Type String[] of the last argument to method printRecord(Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.